# How to correctly bond two 200 amp main panels on a 400 amp service

Tags: grounding, meter, panel

I currently have a 200 amp service with a single 200 amp meter. That meter feeds a 200 amp main panel on the other side of the wall that the meter is mounted to (think standard residential installation). I then have a 100 amp sub panel fed off of that 200 amp main panel. The bonding screw is removed from the sub panel.

I'm going to upgrade to a 400 amp service, replacing my 200 amp meter with a 400 amp meter and replacing the 100 amp sub panel with a 200 amp main panel. This new main panel will be fed by an external disconnect next to the new 400 amp meter and the old 200 amp panel will continue to be fed how it is now.

Do I leave the bonding screw in this new panel or not? What other bonding consideration do I need to account for?

Comment: What you are asking needs at least knowledge of your local electrical code, so which country is this? Perhaps DIY.SE would be a better place to ask? To me it sounds like this is not something a layperson is allowed to do and you would need a qualified and licenced electrician for this, but this again depends on your local electric code.

Comment: I'm in the US, but electrical code doesn't technically apply when you live out in the country. Still, I want to do my work based on best practices. Reading (interpreting) the code is what I'm trying to avoid. I'm capable of performing the work myself and have installed sub panels and external disconnects multiple times and had them inspected by a professional afterwards without issue. I'm just not sure what is best practices or what code requires for the particular modification.

Comment: "electrical code doesn't technically apply when you live out in the country" Your insurance company may not cover you in the case of a mishap if you make your own electrical modifications, _especially_ if they do not follow standards. Insurance companies _love_ to find reasons not to pay out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to DIY.SE